# Overlaying semitransparent layer on a background with Java 3D

Tags: java, java-3d

I'm using Java3D to visualize a room with some primitives in it. I have an image background that I tile so that it fills the entire frame using `background.setImageScaleMode(Background.SCALE_REPEAT);`. Now I would like to add another semitransparent background on top of this background, and I would like to stretch it to cover the screen using `SCALE_FIT_ALL`. This will create an image effect that I cannot otherwise achieve. However, when I try to do this Java 3D complains that `Group.addChild: child already has a parent`.

Other ways of doing the same thing without using backgrounds (e.g. draw it on a 2D primitive) would be a interest too.

So my question is how can I achieve what I want with Java3D?

**MWE:** Image are available [here](https://github.com/juliangarnier/3D-CSS-Solar-System/tree/master/img). I want to draw bg-stars.png with `Background.SCALE_REPEAT` and then on top of that bg-glow.png with `Background.SCALE_FIT_ALL`.

Comment: Hard to say something based on this description. A http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve would be great, but at least some more code might be helpful (e.g. showing where the `child already has a parent` message comes from)

Comment: @Marco13 In Java3D you add a background by creating it (`new Background..`) and then adding it (`Group.addChild`). I've tried to add two backgrounds, i.e. call `Group.addChild` twice. The error message I get when I do this, as I said, is `Group.addChild: child already has a parent`. Example images I would like to superimpose in the way I describe can be found [here](https://github.com/juliangarnier/3D-CSS-Solar-System/tree/master/img) . bg-stars.png should be tiled and (`Background.SCALE_REPEAT`) and bg-glow.png should be superimposed but scaled, (`Background.SCALE_FIT_ALL`).

Comment: The error message suggests that you tried to add the *same* background *twice*, but maybe that's just an artefact of an internal restriction that only allows one background at a time. I'd first have to create a test case to further help here. Maybe someone has more experience with Backgrounds in Java3D

Comment: @Marco13 I know, the error message isn't very well written at all. I hope someone comes along; I'm pretty confident you really cannot have multiple backgrounds and for that reason I'm mainly here to fish for other ideas. My code won't help. Thanks for trying to help me improve the question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not what you actually want to achieve, but too long for a comment:

I did a test of adding multiple Backgrounds, and it "worked" basically (that is: it did not cause an error message). But the documentation of `Background` says

> If multiple Background nodes are active, the Background node that is "closest" to the eye will be used.

Thus, I assume that it is not possible at all to display multiple backgrounds simulataneously at all.

Depending on what you want to achieve, there are probably several possibilities. The following it one approach that might be "close" to what you want. But I am **not** familiar with Backgrounds in Java3D, and assume that there are more elegant, efficient, flexible (or simply: *better*) approaches (like creating a huge, semi-transparent quad with the overlay texture or whatever...)

However, the idea here was to create the background as a single image. Composing BufferedImages is rather easy and offers a lot of possibilities. So I'm taking the `bg-stars.png` image and create a "tiled" version of this image (large enough to fill a certain area - in practice, this could simply be made as large as the maximum screen size). Then I'm composing this with the "overlay" image, `bg-glow.png`, by just painting it over the tiled image.

The resulting image can then be used to create the Background.

At the first glance, the result may look like what you want to achieve, but of course, there may be some caveats. E.g. one has to think about how this could be implemented to adapt to changes of the window size. (Listening for this with a `ComponentListener` and updating the image would be easy, but ... well).

And again: There certainly are *better* solutions. But maybe this can at least serve as a workaround until you find the *better* solution.

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.media.j3d.Background;
import javax.media.j3d.BoundingSphere;
import javax.media.j3d.BranchGroup;
import javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D;
import javax.media.j3d.ImageComponent2D;
import javax.media.j3d.Transform3D;
import javax.media.j3d.TransformGroup;

import com.sun.j3d.utils.applet.MainFrame;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.ColorCube;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.image.TextureLoader;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse;

public class SimpleBackgroundTest extends Applet
{
    private static final int WIDTH = 1200;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 1200;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        System.setProperty("sun.awt.noerasebackground", "true");
        Frame frame = new MainFrame(new SimpleBackgroundTest(), WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }

    public SimpleBackgroundTest()
    {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Canvas3D c = new Canvas3D(SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration());
        add("Center", c);

        BranchGroup group = new BranchGroup();
        group.addChild(createSomeCube());

        BufferedImage stars = null;
        BufferedImage glow = null;
        try
        {
            stars = ImageIO.read(new File("bg-stars.png"));
            glow = ImageIO.read(new File("bg-glow.png"));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedImage tiled = createTiled(stars, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        BufferedImage overlay = createOverlay(tiled, glow);

        Background background = createBackground(overlay);
        group.addChild(background);

        SimpleUniverse universe = new SimpleUniverse(c);
        universe.addBranchGraph(group);
        universe.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
    }

    private static BufferedImage createTiled(
        BufferedImage image, int targetSizeX, int targetSizeY)
    {
        BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(
            targetSizeX, targetSizeY,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = result.createGraphics();
        for (int x = 0; x < targetSizeX; x += image.getWidth())
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < targetSizeY; y += image.getHeight())
            {
                g.drawImage(image, x, y, null);
            }
        }
        g.dispose();
        return result;
    }

    private static BufferedImage createOverlay(
        BufferedImage image, BufferedImage overlay)
    {
        BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(
            image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), 
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = result.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        g.drawImage(overlay, 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), null);
        g.dispose();
        return result;
    }

    private static Background createBackground(BufferedImage image)
    {
        TextureLoader textureLoader = new TextureLoader(image);
        ImageComponent2D imageComponent = textureLoader.getImage();
        Background background = new Background();
        background.setImage(imageComponent);
        background.setImageScaleMode(Background.SCALE_FIT_ALL);
        background.setCapability(Background.ALLOW_IMAGE_WRITE);
        background.setApplicationBounds(new BoundingSphere());
        return background;
    }

    private TransformGroup createSomeCube()
    {
        ColorCube cube = new ColorCube(0.5f);
        Transform3D t = new Transform3D();
        t.rotY(0.2);
        t.setScale(0.1);
        TransformGroup tg = new TransformGroup();
        tg.setTransform(t);
        tg.removeAllChildren();
        tg.addChild(cube);
        return tg;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will look into ComponentListener. Then this will do exactly what I wanted so I'm very grateful :) Right now I cannot figure out why it creates two frames instead of one, and puts the background in the smaller frame. I guess it's only happening for me, but if you have an idea what it might be I would appreciate input. Don't worry about accept, I will accept your answer shortly!

Comment: @Pickett Sorry, I just quickly assembled this from another J3D example. The second screen was created because the universe did not receive the canvas in its constructor. I've slightly cleaned it up (but have to admit that I did not work much with J3D recently, so its "proof of concept" nature may still be visible)